# How to fetch data with navigation properties in One to many Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, mapping, one-to-many

I am trying to fetch data with One to many relationship using navigation properties in linq queries but i got ArgumentNullException error.

My entities in here to creating two one to many relationships between them.

```
public class Category : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryInfo { get; set; }
        public double CategoryPrice { get; set; }
        public List<MemberCategory>? Members { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<Description>? Descriptions { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<Image>? Images { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<Trainer>? Trainers { get; set; }
    }

public class Description : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int DescriptionId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionName { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }


public class Image : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

And also i composed a viewmodel to send frontend side

```
    public class CategoryDescriptionImageViewModel
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryInfo { get; set; }
        public double CategoryPrice { get; set; }
        public List<string> CategoryDescriptions { get; set; }
        public List<string> CategoryImages { get; set; }
    }
```

In here compiler gives me possible null reference in Images and Descriptions.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            var categories = _categoryService.GetAll().Select(i => new CategoryDescriptionImageViewModel
            {
                CategoryId = i.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = i.CategoryName,
                CategoryInfo = i.CategoryInfo,
                CategoryPrice = i.CategoryPrice,
                CategoryImages = **i.Images**.Where(x => x.CategoryId == i.CategoryId).Select(x => x.ImageName).ToList(),
                CategoryDescriptions = **i.Descriptions**.Where(x => x.CategoryId == i.CategoryId).Select(x => x.DescriptionName).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            return View(categories);
        }
```

Comment: are you using MVC6 or core?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core with MVC Architecture

Comment: Have u tried define the categories as List<string>? Also amend the query for this as I. Images.where().any? I.images.where() : null